# Move button inside the chart

Tags: javascript, html, css, kendo-ui

I have the following project which I display signals on the chart. And recently I have implemented pdf export. However I want this button to be on the top or below the legends. I could not able to figure that out.

```
<div id="chart"></div>
<button class='export-pdf k-button'>Save as PDF</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a slightly different solution to the one provided. I wrapped your chart div in a relatively positioned div:

```
#chart-container { position: relative; }
```

Then I give the button absolute positioning so it will always be absolutely positioned relatively to the wrapping container (and not the window).

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/beg04nwf/

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot for the great answer. I would like to know what if I have several signals, dont you think the button will be overlapping with legeneds?

Comment: That's true. You could solve that a couple of different ways: The one I would suggest is something you are 100% positive will work. In this case, instead of using the "top" property for the absolutely positioned button, you could use "bottom" and give it some "padding" (quotes because you won't use the padding property). Here's another fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamjpg/4vv4nwrb/ - This way you know that the button will always align with the bottom of the chart.

Answer (score 1):

[Try this code.](http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/43)

```
.k-button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -45px;
    position: relative;
}
```